# How do I get Pylint message IDs to show up after pylint-1.0.0?

Tags: pylint

Starting with `pylint-1.0.0` the `--include-ids` argument is no longer allowed.

How do I get:

```
************* Module foo.bar
E:199,11: Module 'yaml' has no 'scanner' member (no-member)
************* Module foo.baz
W:153,27: Unused variable '_filenames' (unused-variable)
```

to show the IDs (e.g. W0142), for each warning?

Comment: On my setup this option is no longer displayed by `pylint --long-help`. It might be that `man pylint` is outdated and that this option is not included in version 1.0.0 :(.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The new way to specify this is the command line parameter `'--msg-template={path}:{line}: [{msg_id}({symbol}), {obj}] {msg}'`.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Note that also the column can of a pylint message can be shown. Usage:
--msg-template={column}

Comment: @r3m0t where can I find documentation on the available fields for `--msg-template`?

Comment: @JaceBrowning https://bitbucket.org/logilab/pylint/src/02db08561a8ef462ca7279c12916e54eb362d47d/reporters/__init__.py?at=default#cl-40

Comment: Whow, cool: Instead of '--include-ids=y' I now have to write ''--msg-template={path}:{line}: [{msg_id}({symbol}), {obj}] {msg}'' Now that is easy and intuitive! :-) Not your fault I know, thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: @JohannesOvermann, you can disable errors based on symbolic names instead of codes now (e.g. `# pylint: disable=redefined-outer-name`)

Comment: FWIW, this is now in the [docs](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/wiki/Python%3A---pylint).

Comment: saved my day! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The proper command which can be used is

```
python3 -m pylint --msg-template="{path}||{msg_id}||{symbol}||{category}||{line}||{column}||{msg}" sscript.py
```