# PyLint 1.0.0 with PyDev + Eclipse: "include-ids" option no longer allowed, breaks Eclipse integration

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, pylint

As noted in this question: [How do I get Pylint message IDs to show up after pylint-1.0.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133264/how-do-i-get-pylint-message-ids-to-show-up-after-pylint-1-0-0)

pylint 1.0.0 no longer accepts "include-ids" option.  (It returns "lint.py: error: no such option: --include-ids").  Unfortunately, in the integation with PyDev/Eclipse, there is this little nugget:
"The --include-ids=y is always included...".

How to disable that argument so that Pylint will work with Eclipse?

[I know, other alternatives include installing an older version of Pylint or running pylint from command line without that option (which does work), but I'd like to have the integration with Eclipse.]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should be already fixed in the latest nightly build. Please grab it there.

See: http://pydev.org/download.html for details on how to get it.

Comment: @FabioZadrozny is there any way to get the IDs to still show up? The IDs have disappeared after this nightly build.

Answer (score 3):

To make ID's appear in the Problem View on Eclispe using PyDev, make sure you use

```
msg-template={msg_id}:{line:3d},{column}: {obj}: {msg}
```

in pylintrc or on the command line options.  Eclipse needs this to parse the PyLint output.

Comment: I had to all the line: `--msg-template="{msg_id}:{line:3d},{column}: {obj}: {msg}"` (with quotes)

Answer (score 1):

The following option works with pylint v1.4.3 under pydev v3.9.2:

```
--msg-template="{msg_id}:{line:3d},{column:2d}:{msg}"
```

Note: Don't put space(s) after the semicolons otherwise it does not work.