# How to write messge ids to html file with pylint 1.1

Tags: pylint

We recently upgraded to pylint-1.1 from pylint-0.28, and I can no longer get the message ids written to the html files generated when using --output-format=html.

Changes in pylint 1.X took away the --include-ids option, and these questions:

[How do I get Pylint message IDs to show up after pylint-1.0.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133264/how-do-i-get-pylint-message-ids-to-show-up-after-pylint-1-0-0)
[PyLint 1.0.0 with PyDev + Eclipse: "include-ids" option no longer allowed, breaks Eclipse integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362779/pylint-1-0-0-with-pydev-eclipse-include-ids-option-no-longer-allowed-break)

suggest using the --message-template option to restore it, but that only seems to work with screen output. So, currently the 'type' column in the html file only contains one of the five message types. How can I get the message name or message id into the html files instead?

Also, FWIW the pylint documentation here

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylint
http://docs.pylint.org/features.html#options

still mentions the --include-ids option, and doesn't mention --message-template.

Mark E. Hamilton

Answer (score 0):

That's right that this option disappears in pylint 1.1.

Text reporters advantagously get the `message-template` instead, but HTML loose a bit of configurability on the way. Anyway IMO, the html reports should be fixed to systematically include the symbolic name and that's it.

Please submit an issue on https://bitbucket.org/logilab/pylint/issues about that.

Comment: issue is at https://bitbucket.org/logilab/pylint/issue/135/how-to-write-messge-name-or-id-to-html