# Get error code for disabling in pylint from error message

Tags: python, pylint

If you have a main.py file
and from the command line run
pylint main.py

Pylint throws errors/status/etc like
Wrong hanging indentation.
                    'name':
                |   ^ (bad-continuation)

How do I find out what the error code of (bad-continuation) is so I can disable it?

I know I can run pylint main.py -d E1101 -d F0401

So I want either a master list of pylint error codes mapped to messages or a way to look it up from the messages.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean like this? <strike>[PyLint Codes](https://www.pylintcode.info/)(broken link)</strike>

For how to have PyLint directly print out the relevant codes, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18495350/1191087).

Comment: The first list is missing some but that second link is the jam.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, you don't need the message *shortcodes* anymore.

The message id of `bad-continuation` is simply `bad-continuation`.

```
pylint main.py -d bad-continuation
```