# How to sort a pyLint output result?

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm, pylint

Is it possible, for example, to sort by line or by category or both?

I saw that is possible to use a template: [How do I get Pylint message IDs to show up after pylint-1.0.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133264/how-do-i-get-pylint-message-ids-to-show-up-after-pylint-1-0-0)

In PyCharm, I configured a External Tools to call pyLint:

```
$FileName$ --msg-template={line}:" "[{msg_id}"-"({symbol})," "{obj}]:" "{msg}
```

Now, I would like to sort this output result.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On Linux, I pipe the output of pylint through sort:

```
pylint file.py | sort -t ":" -k 2,2n
```

This uses a colon character as the field separator, and sorts on the second field, applying a numeric sort.

PyCharm, however, won't let you use a pipe character in an External Tool, so you'll have to make the command into a shell script:

```
pylint $1 $2 $3 | sort -t ":" -k 2,2n
```

The only problem with this approach is that pylint's "hanging indent" warnings will appear at the top of the output.
I personally find this a minor inconvenience.

Comment: for directories sort by `filename` and then by `line` with `pylint directory | sort -t : -k 1,1 -k 2,2n`